# replace CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes

Tags: objective-c

code :

```
#import "EncodeURLString.h"

@implementation EncodeURLString

- (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("!*'\";$,#[] "), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}

- (NSString *)safeEcapeString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *result = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"\\:"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"\\;"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\\,"];
    return [result autorelease];
}

@end
```

this code is causing the # tag in my url to be converted into %23 is there a way that i make it stop converting the hash tags? i've tried removing it from here CFSTR("!*'\";$,#[] ") but it doesn't work it still converts it. any help or tips would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the hash from the `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped` parameter and use `CFSTR("#")` for `charactersToLeaveUnescaped`.

Comment: WOW thanks a lot, am not a coder so was a bit baffled on how to fix it :-)